# How to communicate in your portfolio that code has been modified since you deployed it?

Tags: professionalism, developer, portfolio

It is inevitable that as a web developer, you publish a site and then someone else takes over updating and editing the site. How do you say in your portfolio, that you are responsible for the code up to a certain date, but not after?

This is important especially if the quality of the code changes and you want to politely distance yourself from something written differently than you would have done.

Edit:

I'm a front end dev so it's pretty easy for a potential hirer to view the CSS, JS and HTML that I write. I'll make sure to put the launch date on each project. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be implicitly obvious when you state that between June 2013 and March 2015, you worked at company A, and pushed code to repo B. Anyone who reads this will understand that any changes made since March 2015 is not yours.

I assume, given the nature of the question, that the Git/SVN/BitBucket/whatever repositories are OpenSource. In that sense, it should be easy for them to evaluate, to some extent, the quality of your code.

One possible trap is when you need to make a workaround for someone else's poor quality code. By looking at your commit alone, *your* code might look hacky.

Comment: That's why adding comments to your code is important especially when you do things that are hacky. Right now I have the problem having to work around a bizarre bug in someone else's code, so the bug and the workaround will be thoroughly documented.

Comment: @gnasher729 - Seconded. Creating a hack is usually just a workaround. The real sin is not documenting it.

Comment: I wouldn't assume the code is open source; for web code, you can of course observe the rendered output by visiting the site.

Comment: Why would you assume that the repositories are open source? Can you point me to the StackExchange code repository, for example?

Comment: @Happy - I made the assumption because OP referenced the "quality of the code". While all we see on the website itself is the output of the code, the quality is quite invisible to us. For all we know, the SE source code echoes every character individually. It can look good on the outside, and still be poor quality code.

Comment: @Alec Yeah, that's a fair point. But you see, if a website consists full of scrolling marquees, popup alerts, and other irritants, I can see the website being considered "poor quality". You are correct, it doesn't imply the *code* is poor, but that is just a technicality. I have never come across anyone saying, "Oh, the output is great, but the code is poor" (or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

If it has been a fairly long time since you worked for a company and on their website, I don't think anyone is going to make you solely responsible for its current condition. During the interview process, you may review the site and let them know if it does or does not reflect your level of work.

Hopefully, you have other items in your portfolio that demonstrate your current level of work and they won't rely too much on the other site. If they prefer the existing site, you have some explaining to do.